# Why was Jacob's family segregated into large tents?

Tags: genesis, context, cultural-analysis, israel

In Genesis 31:33, when Laban went to look for his stolen teraphim, the author notes:

> And Laban went into Jacob’s tent, into Leah’s tent, and into the two
>   maids’ tents, but he did not find them. Then he went out of Leah’s
>   tent and entered Rachel’s tent.

Why was Jacob's family segregated per wife? Also, why did Jacob have a tent for himself? Shouldn't he be together with at least one of his wives?

Comment: Consider the Chinese character 安 (ān, as in "Tiān ān mén, 天安门", Gate of Heavenly Peace ), meaning "peace", "calm", "still", "quiet".  It is composed of two parts:  a roof (symbolizing a house), and a woman.  The important thing to note is that there is only one woman under the roof.  A house without a woman is not peaceful.  A house with more than one woman is not peaceful.  (Note, this is not my sexism showing, it is how the character's origins were described to me.)

Comment: Because they wouldn't fit into small ones?  Sorry, couldn't resist.  Great question and I have no clue what the answer is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer on Ancient Hebrew Research Center in an article written by Fred H. Wight:

> The Oriental tent is usually oblong in shape, and is divided into two,
>   and sometimes three apartments by goat's hair curtains. The entrance
>   leads into the apartment for the men, which also serves as the
>   reception apartment. Beyond this is the apartment for the women and
>   children. And sometimes there is a third apartment for servants or for
>   cattle.
>
> The women in the inner apartment are screened from the view of those
>   in the reception room, but they can hear what goes on in that room.
>   Thus Sarah in her apartment overheard what the angel guest said in the
>   reception apartment of Abraham's tent (Gen. 18:10-15). In some cases
>   there is a separate tent for the women. It took several tents to care
>   for the large family of Jacob. Reference is made to Jacob's tent, to
>   Leah's tent, to Rachel's tent, and to the tent of the two
>   maidservants; (Gen. 31:33).

[Here's the link to the full article](https://www.ancient-hebrew.org/manners/tent-dwellings.htm).